# Is there any nuance between 'in terms of' and 'in the case of'?

Tags: meaning, difference

> 1. **In terms of** structure, they are the first part of a noun
>    group; that is, they come before any of the other words that go with a
>    noun.
> 2. **In the case of** the **Head Position Parameter** (i.e. the parameter which
>    determines the relative positioning of heads with respect to their
>    complements), the language faculty allows only a binary set of
>    possibilities – namely that a given kind of structure in a given
>    language is either consistently head-first or consistently head-last.

Are they interchangeable? To me,I think 'in the case of' is more specific  than 'in terms of'. Namely, we use 'in terms of **structure**' and 'in the case of **somewhat specific structure**'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They aren't interchangeable.

'In terms of' is used to specify which **particular area of something** you wish to discuss. In terms of money, my new job is very good, but in terms of interest it is poor.

'In the case of' is used when you wish to discuss **some particular thing or person**, especially if you wish to isolate it or them from others. British car brands have had a difficult time financially in recent years. In the case of Rolls-Royce, this led to the company being sold to BMW in 2003.